# How to best use left joins in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**Apologies for the poorly worded title. I couldn't think of a way to succinctly express my question. If someone has a better title please suggest it.**

I have what I assume to be a common pattern in Rails. However, for the life of me I cannot find an acceptable answer.

The problem is this:

I have 3 models. Book, User and Reading. They can be expressed in ActiveRecord classes:

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :readings, dependent: :destroy

  validates :title, presence: true
end


class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :readings, dependent: :destroy

  validates :name, presence: true
end

class Reading < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :book
end
```

I would like to create a resource which is `GET /users/1/reading-list` which will contain *all* books in the database and indicate whether the user has read the book. An example output might be:

```
{
  "user": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "mrwillihog"
  },
  "books": [
    {
      "book": {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "To Kill a Mockingbird"
      },
      "read": false
    },
    {
      "book": {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "East of Eden"
      },
      "read": true
    },
    {
      "book": {
        "id": 3,
        "title": "On the Road"
      },
      "read": false
    }
  ]
}
```

Now, in SQL terms this is a simple left join:

```
SELECT books.*, CASE WHEN readings.id IS NOT NULL THEN true ELSE false END as read
FROM "books" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "readings" ON "readings"."book_id" = "books"."id" and user_id = 1;
```

And indeed, if I force Rails to run that query I can achieve my desired output:

```
book  = Book.select("books.*, CASE WHEN readings.id IS NOT NULL THEN true ELSE false END as read")
    .joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN readings ON readings.book_id = books.id AND readings.user_id = 1")
    .first

book.read # => false
```

However, this does not feel like an idiomatic solution. It feels like I'm writing too much SQL and it also feels wrong having a `read` attribute on the Book model, as it is not directly relevant to a book.

So my question is this:

**What is the 'Rails' way to solve this kind of problem?**

I feel like I'm missing an abstraction or a feature of rails that enables me to more succinctly solve this type of problem.

**EDIT:** To address iceman's comment, I can't use the `left_outer_join` method as it does not scope the readings to a particular user.

```
# Marks books as read when they have only been read by other users
books = Book.left_outer_join(:readings)

# Removes books not read by user.
books = Book.left_outer_join(:readings).where(readings: { user_id: current_user.id })
```

Comment: Rails 5 has `Book.left_outer_join(:readings)`

Comment: That isn't scoped to a particular user though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I created a `BookList` class to encapsulate the behaviour. Internally it uses a set (thanks to @david-aldridge for the suggestion) to determine whether you have read a book or not.

```
class BookList
  attr_reader :items

  def initialize(books, readings)
    read_books_set = readings.pluck(:book_id).to_set
    @items = books.map do |book|
      BookList::Item.new(book, book.id.in?(read_books_set))
    end
  end

  class Item
    attr_reader :book

    def initialize(book, read)
      @book = book
      @read = read
    end

    def read?
      @read
    end
  end
end
```

Initialize it in your controller:

```
@book_list = BookList.new(Book.all, current_user.readings)
```

You could then use it in a view:

```
<% @book_list.items.each do |book_list_item| %>
  <h2><%= book_list_item.book.title %></h2>
  <p>Read: <%= book_list_item.read %></p>
<% end %>
```

If you wanted you could make `BookList` enumerable, yielding a book and whether it has been read or not:

```
class BookList
  include Enumerable
  attr_reader :items

  def initialize(books, readings)
    read_books_set = readings.pluck(:book_id).to_set
    @items = books.map do |book|
      BookList::Item.new(book, book.id.in?(read_books_set))
    end
  end

  def each(&block)
    @items.each do |item|
      block.call(item.book, item.read?)
    end
  end

  class Item
    attr_reader :book
    def initialize(book, read)
      @book = book
      @read = read
    end

    def read?
      @read
    end
  end
end
```

And simplify your view:

```
<% @book_list.each do |book, read| %>
  <h2><%= book.title %></h2>
  <p>Read: <%= read %></p>
<% end %>
```

I think this solution keeps the concern of whether a book has been read by a particular user out of the Book model which is good and it is also flexible enough to allow different lists of books and readings, so I'm happy.

Answer (score 1):

So you want all books and whether or not they've been read by a particular user?  That would be a left join where the user id is null or matches in the join clause.

I'm struggling to get it to work with AR's `joins()` method, so here it is in raw sql:

```
books = Book.find_by_sql(["
      select 
        books.id id,
        books.name name,
        readings.id read
      from 
        books
        left join readings on readings.book_id = books.id and readings.user_id = :user_id
      ", { user_id: current_user.id }])
```

Then you can call `.read?` on a result to see if the current user has read it.

Comment: This would filter out Books that have been read by another user but not by me. I.e. user_id is not null but it isnt my ID either.

Comment: Edited to use the user_id in the join as well as the where clause

Comment: This produces the desired SQL (although I think where clause is now unnecessary). However, trying to render whether a user has read a book or not in my view produces N+1 queries. As an aside, I couldn't get the `...readings.user_id = :user_id, user_id: current_user.id` syntax to work - "Can't join 'Book' to association named 'user_id'"

Comment: Yeah, I'm having issues with the `.join` too, I've changed it to `find_by_sql`

Answer (score 1):

Not quite the answer you're looking for, you might query for all books and then check whether each is in the list that the user has read:

```
user_book_ids = @user.book_ids
```

... and for each book ...

```
read = book.id.in?(user_book_ids)
```

Not perfect, but maybe good enough.

Edit: It might be worth using a Set instead of an Array ...

```
2.2.5 :001 >     require 'set'
 => true 
2.2.5 :002 >     require 'benchmark'
 => true 
2.2.5 :003 > 
2.2.5 :004 >     all_books = (1..100000).to_a ; 0
 => 0 
2.2.5 :005 >     read_books_array = all_books.sample(1000) ; 0
 => 0 
2.2.5 :006 >     read_books_set = Set.new(read_books_array) ; 0
 => 0 
2.2.5 :007 >     
2.2.5 :008 >     Benchmark.bm do |x|
2.2.5 :009 >       x.report("array:") {all_books.each{|b| read_books_array.include?(b)}}
2.2.5 :010?>       x.report("set:  ") {all_books.each{|b| read_books_set.include?(b)}}
2.2.5 :011?>     end
       user     system      total        real
array:  0.500000   0.000000   0.500000 (  0.499425)
set:    0.010000   0.000000   0.010000 (  0.013016)
```

Comment: Yeh, this definitely works but I'm convinced there must be a nicer way! At least with this way it avoids adding the `read` attribute to Book - so I guess it's less magic. My only concern would be when the book list gets large.

Comment: @MrWillihog Always worth a test -- it turns out that converting the array to a set may be worthwhile.

Comment: Thanks David. I quite like this approach. I'll wait and see if anyone else has a suggestion and if not I'll mark this as the accepted answer.